# Excel condense data

Tags: excel

I have data in an excel spreadsheet in the form of

```
John | Age      | 24  
John | Location | Australia  
John | Salary   | $5000  
Sue  | Age      | 28   
Sue  | Location | England  
Sue  | Salary   | $6000
```

Is there an easy function to sort into a table along the lines of:

```
Name | Age   |  Location  |  Salary  
John | 24    | Australia  | $5000  
Sue  | 28    | England    | $6000
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use PowerQuery ...!  Go to `Data` -> `Get Data` -> `From File` -> `From Workbook` and then follow these steps.

##### Rename first column to Name ...

[image: Step 1]

##### Select Column2 and Pivot the data ...

[image: Step 2]

##### Use these options in the pivot ...

[image: Step 3]

### Voila!

[image: Result]

##### Select Close and Load to populate a new sheet ...

[image: Close and Load]

##### Result ...

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

Formula in `F2` cell I used-

```
=INDEX($C$1:$C$6,MAX(($A$1:$A$6=$E2)*($B$1:$B$6=F$1)*(ROW($C$1:$C$6))))
```

If you have ***Excel-365*** then you can use `UNIQUE()` function to `E2` cell.

```
=UNIQUE(A1:A6)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
=ROWS($A$6:A6)*3
=INDEX($A$6:$C$11;E6;1)
=INDEX($A$6:$C$11;(E6)-2;3)
=INDEX($A$6:$C$11;(E6)-1;3)
=INDEX($A$6:$C$11;E6;3)
```

[image]